# Spruce sudden loss of needles

Tags: tree-care

I have a spruce that had green needles one day then in 2-3 days all the needles fell off the tree, still green and soft. I have no idea what could cause this but found it odd.

I am not sure if I should cut the tree down or if my other much larger spruces will have the same issue.

Will try to add pictures later

Comment: Is it planted in the ground or in a pot, how long have you had this particular plant, when did you  plant it, where are you in the world and a photo might be helpful

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: It is in the ground, it actually may be a hello kitty. It is about 40 foot tall I think. The tee has been there since I moved in, about 7 years ago. Not sure how old it is.